# python script list or read value

Tags: python

current python script key value is

```
"key" : "value"
```

changed to

```
 "key" : ["value"]
```

the script no longer read or list the value, I have tried \ to escape the "[" what else should I do? I am new for python.

thanks

Comment: this is confusing? what script? how are you calling it? is this a dictionary? please be more specific

Comment: `somedic['key'][0]` or  `"key" : "[value]"`

Comment: Very unclear question...

Comment: Please share a [mcve] that shows how you produce this key-value, how you read this key-value, what you changed, the expected result, the actual result, and any error messages that you are getting. It is currently unclear how this key value is used or what "*script no longer read or list the value*" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably need more context from you , 
but in short, you can change it to a actual string as in:

> "key" : "[\"value\"]"

or

> "key" : "['value']"

Answer (score 0):

If this is a dictionary like your question implies, you can just assign to the key the element of your embedded list like so:

```
dict[key] = dict[key][0]
```